# Redirect port 80 to 8080 and make it work on local machine

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I redirected traffic for port 80 to 8080 on my machine with

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

It works fine for all the world except my own machine. I am a developer and I need to redirect port 80 to 8080 for myself.

My IP is `192.168.0.111`

My web server runs on port 8080

I wish to open website from `http://192.168.0.111/` instead of `http://192.168.0.111:8080/` from same machine where server runs.

Comment: Excuse me for the abberation, but what is the purpose of forwarding port 80 to 8080?

Comment: @mattdipasquale, normal users can't access port 80 so you couldn't run a web service like python flask as a normal user.

Comment: Why don't you just bind the web server to port 80?

Comment: i'd guess its because non-root user cannot bind to ports 80/443 and he doesnt want to run his web service as root..

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You need to use the `OUTPUT` chain as the packets meant for the *loopback* interface do not pass via the `PREROUTING` chain. The following should work; run as `root`:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: Does port 80 required to be gloabally accesible? I tried your solution, my port number 8080 is accessible but 80 is not hence it did not worked. @heemayl

Comment: This did not work, not sure why this is voted up

Comment: @Diyoda_ Please define _did not work_.

Comment: @Alper I think you didn't read the OPs question.

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: how to stop this forwarding? EDIT - FOUND IT: replace -A with -D in that command

Comment: not working on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Probably we should first enable the port forwarding: `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` (or `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`). Then make the change persistent, by uncommenting these lines in '/etc/sysctl.conf'.

Comment: This did work for me without modification on Ubuntu 220.04, after the sysctl commands in the comment above

Answer (score 24):

Simple just use iptables allowing both port 80 and 8080 then redirect 80 to 8080 make sure you are assigning to the correct nic.. in example I use eth0

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working on Ubuntu 19

Comment: After would be nice to save iptable changes ``sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent``

Comment: Works for me on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me.

```
$ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: +1 works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 (at least for TCP), did port 7000->7001 and servers listening on port 7001 received incoming connections from port 7000  :)

Comment: make sure to use the correct network interface tho, it isn't called `eth0` on all systems

Comment: works perfectly in 20.04

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the `iptables`, You could try:

`sudo ssh -gL 80:127.0.0.1:8080 localhost`

Comment: That is an option but it is not exactly what I want because I already have web server on port 80. I will prefer to do it with iptables and keep web server on port 80 running. I guess I just have to apply rule to different step instead of `PREROUTING`

Comment: Yes - this will cause a port conflict if you have something listening that you are port forwarding to as Max suggested.   The above answer is the more general case.

Comment: I get a "Connection refused" when attempting this solution.

Comment: @mitchus it sounds like you don't have an SSH service.  Try `sudo apt install openssh-server`.

Answer (score 1):

i have been trying very hard to forward a port from 8080 to 80 , but i am unable to find a right solution but then this worked for me https://askubuntu.com/a/579540/1611784

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80