# IPTABLES - Forwarding 80 to 8080 to vagrant's apache

Tags: ssh, iptables, vagrant

I was trying to forward my 80 access to 8080 with IPTABLES without success, then I read this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444729/redirect-port-80-to-8080-and-make-it-work-on-local-machine/579515?noredirect=1#comment801009_579515)

And it finally worked for me, after all the IPTABLES configurations I tried this command made it..

`sudo ssh -gL 80:127.0.0.1:8080 localhost`

what does this command really do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in command `sudo ssh -gL 80:127.0.0.1:8080 localhost`

```
option -g - Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports
option -L - [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
             Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be
             forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.  This
             works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side,
             optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a
             connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
             the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port
             hostport from the remote machine.  Port forwardings can also be
             specified in the configuration file.
```

traffic from port 80 redirected to port 8080 on localhost