# How to redirect HTTP call on a port to another port on local env?

Tags: networking, proxy, hostname, hosts

**Problematic**

I would like to call `http://myapp.dev` in my web browser and "redirect" this call to `http://myapp.dev:6547` or `http://127.0.0.1:6547`, like a proxy would do.

This way, I could have an Apache or nginx listening to `6547` without having to write the port in my web browser to reach MyApp locally hosted.

**Question**

Is that possible with native Ubuntu/Linux tools to do this?

**Solutions proposed**

I've seen this post:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729034/can-i-map-a-hostname-and-a-port-with-etc-hosts

but I don't want to install nginx to do this.

I've also seen this post:

- [redirect port 80 to 8080 and make it work on local machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444729/redirect-port-80-to-8080-and-make-it-work-on-local-machine)

but iptables are cleaned each reboot and I want a persistent solution without having to install `iptables-persistent` package.

Comment: What about apache (to act as reverse proxy)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect port 80 to 8080 and make it work on local machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444729/redirect-port-80-to-8080-and-make-it-work-on-local-machine)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I would like to use a native package, not installing a new one, so same problem with Apacha than nginx...

Comment: @darckcrystale, maybe you should redefine your understanding for "native" package as apache is native package in Ubuntu. Or use the idea in mentioned by heemayl question

Comment: @RomeoNinov I am reading the post suggested by heemayl :) thanks for the Apache suggest, I shouldn't post my question here, I want a solution which works on most of Linux distributions, sorry...

Comment: @heemayl you can see my edit, I don't think your solution could work for me :/

Comment: @darckcrystale You don't have to install `iptables-persistent`. Leverage some startup script e.g. `/etc/rc.local`.