Ubuntu 22.04 - How to change listen port for the native remote desktop?
First of all, I do not use xrdp so, it's not gonna be in /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini. I can RDP from Windows to Ubuntu (hosted on VirtualBox - Bridged Connection) just fine via 3389 but I prefer using a different port. I have already added a new port in the Windows Registry and allowed it through Windows Defender Firewall (Incoming).
My problem is, that I have no clue where in Ubuntu I can change the listening port from 3389 to another for RDP.

I can RDP from Windows to Ubuntu via 3389
I want to RDP from Windows to Ubuntu via 33895


What's the purpose exactly? If it is to completely shut 3389 on the Ubuntu host I think you may be out of luck, as I went through the dconf settings for rdp and it appears as though there's no way to configure the listening port (so the solution here would be using a different rdp server);  otherwise there are ways to work around it and have your Windows client connect to a different port, only subsequently redirecting traffic to 3389.

Thank you for your response. I'm about to lose my mind looking for answer because I'm that kind of person, prefer things in Vanilla. My plan was, since I have multiple VMs running simultaneously, I thought it would be cool to RDP each VM per assigned port. I have successfully done so with my host OS and other Windows VM and wishing I can do the same with Ubuntu.

How about this then? https://askubuntu.com/q/444729/380067 , you could configure it slightly differently on each machine so to expose a different port for the Windows client to connect, with traffic behind the scenes being redirected to 3389

Thanks. I will give it a shot and get back to you with the result.

Routing ip/port did not work so, I just ended up using xrdp. Wish the native RDP have the same "/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini" config file where you can simply change the listen port to whatever you want. Appreciate the help, xrdp does the job so I may as well stick with it :)

Well that's unfortunate (I'm sure that can be done in multiple ways, iptabels, netcat etc, not sure about how correct would be the method I linked), but anyways if xrdp works for you, good enough. Yeah I too use the native gnome server, and I too feel like it's not very customizable. I guess it's build with simplicity in mind, which is a plus in other ways

You could find out which process has port 3399 (and which to reconfigure) with sudo lsof -i:3389
